# Router Speed Control from android mobile?

Tags: android

Could someone help me to control router speed from my android device

Please find the code mentioned below to get the internet speed. 
But I want to know how speed decrease from actual speed.

```
ConnectivityManager myConnManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo myNetworkInfo = myConnManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        WifiManager myWifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo myWifiInfo = myWifiManager.getConnectionInfo();

        textMac.setText(myWifiInfo.getMacAddress());

        if (myNetworkInfo.isConnected()){
            int myIp = myWifiInfo.getIpAddress();

            textConnected.setText("--- CONNECTED ---");

            int intMyIp3 = myIp/0x1000000;
            int intMyIp3mod = myIp%0x1000000;

            int intMyIp2 = intMyIp3mod/0x10000;
            int intMyIp2mod = intMyIp3mod%0x10000;

            int intMyIp1 = intMyIp2mod/0x100;
            int intMyIp0 = intMyIp2mod%0x100;

            textIp.setText(String.valueOf(intMyIp0)
                            + "." + String.valueOf(intMyIp1)
                            + "." + String.valueOf(intMyIp2)
                            + "." + String.valueOf(intMyIp3)
            );

            textSsid.setText(myWifiInfo.getSSID());
            textBssid.setText(myWifiInfo.getBSSID());




            textSpeed.setText(String.valueOf(myWifiInfo.getLinkSpeed()) + " " + WifiInfo.LINK_SPEED_UNITS);



            textRssi.setText(String.valueOf(myWifiInfo.getRssi()));
        }
```

Comment: Do you want to limit your own down/upload-speed in the current application or of the whole device in general?

Comment: The whole device i want to  speed reduce

Comment: This is not possible without rooting your device.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to limit the Down- or Upload-Speed of your whole device without rooting it.

See https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/53890/how-to-limit-throttle-wifi-data-speed-on-my-android-device for further details.